# Power Pivot / DAX - Add column that flags all entries for customers who meet criteria in any of their rows

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I have a large database (2 million rows). There are many columns but the two relevant ones are CustomerID and AccountType. A customer can have more than one account type and if they do this will show as different rows in the database. If any of a customers accounts are AccountType = Premium, then they are a Premium customer.

I want to add a column in PowerPivot that will state whether a customer is Premium or not. So for example:

```
CustomerID          Account Type      Custom Column

1                   Basic             Premium
2                   Deposit           Not Premium
3                   Savings           Not Premium
1                   Premium           Premium
```

So in my example because customer 1 has a Premium account in the last row, the first row is also flagged as Premium. To make it one step trickier, there are actually a few codes, so it could be Premium1, Premium2 etc.

I think I could do this by creating a separate table and linking the two, but I would prefer to avoid this step if possible to keep the file size down.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the expression for the calculated column:

```
Custom Column =
IF (
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            Table,
            [CustomerID] = EARLIER ( Table[CustomerID] )
                && [Account Type] = "Premium"
        )
    )
        > 0,
    "Premium",
    "Not Premium"
)
```

It is not tested but should work, let me know if this works for you.